# Local development credential manager and best practices

Tags: windows, password-management, azure

I've long since been storing credentials to databases and services in local configuration files during development. Sometimes these need to be to production systems, which makes this a security issue.

I'm wondering what the best practice here would be. I don't want to manually enter credentials on each startup of my apps during development and using something using environment variables seems also inconvenient (I'm often using Visual Studio).

I'm very pleased with password managers like LastPass as an end-user, which queries me for a master passphrase and stored credentials on disk only in an encrypted fashion. So I'm wondering if something like this exists for the niche of developers needing an API to request credentials from: My apps could connect to a service that encrypts the credentials only once per machine boot.

What options are there? What do others do?

Comment: this question is basically product recommendation and there for out of scope... but as a hint, take a look at Ansible, Hashicorp Vault and how you could use such tools to configure and store credentials.

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem. Why do people doing development need credentials to production systems?

Comment: @ThomasOwens It could be done differently, but it's a lot of effort to create plausible demo data that is sufficient for development in my scenario. The sensitive part of the data doesn't come from the app itself, it's imported from third parties and as such is not easy to mock. It would be more practical to forgo a local machine altogether and work on a remote one.

Comment: You can avoid sending/storing username/password by using integrated security.  You can use the DefaultAppPool identity for this and add specific permissions to the DB.  Only executables run as the DefaultAppPool will be able to access the DB (or any other users you've added to the DB permissions.)

Comment: @pcalkins Interesting idea. I don't have a domain controller though, so I'm not sure how complicated it would be for me go that route. What makes this even more complicated is that I maintain applications in multiple Azure directories. But maybe tying this to the Windows login is something to think about.

Comment: If you DB is in Azure, maybe see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-sql-database?tabs=windowsclient%2Cefcore%2Cdotnet

Comment: @pcalkins Local machines can't have managed identities - that's something only Azure resources have.

Comment: for Windows servers that host the SQL DB, you can add permissions per user and have the backend code running as a user with the least amount of privileges necessary.  That code would provide information from the DB per user based on it's own authentication/authorization scheme.  Only that code (and DB admins) should should have direct access to the DB.  If you need to store DB user/password somewhere a config file is commonly used (stored in a secure directory that only the code can access), but you might consider DPAPI for encryption in Windows.  (or your platform's secure method)

Comment: @pcalkins DPAPI is interesting, but the managed identities you mentioned earlier may also actually be an option after all. It seems that there is a way - in all of VS, VS Code and Shells - to authenticate against Azure in these environments once and then allow code that is run under them to use the security context already established. I haven't tried that yet but it seems to be what I was initially imagining.